# How to add geo location in elasticsearch index

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using `elasticsearch` with `php` and I want to search with Geo Distance Query but after reading some articles on google I have to add `geo location` in my current indexed code but not getting any idea how to add.

```
$indexed = $client->index([
    'index' => 'users',
    'type' => 'user',
    'body' => [
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'company' => $company,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'streetAddress' => $streetAddress,
        'route' => $route,
        'city' => $locality,
        'state' => $state,
        'postalCode' => $postalCode,
        'country' => $country,
        'latitude' => $latitude,
        'longitude' => $longitude,
        'content' => $content,
        'date' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ]
]);
```

I am referring this [Geo Location and Search](https://www.elastic.co/blog/geo-location-and-search) article but not getting any idea how to implement and use search query.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your document you need to inject location, like this :

```
$indexed = $client->index([
'index' => 'users',
'type' => 'user',
'body' => [
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'company' => $company,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'streetAddress' => $streetAddress,
    'route' => $route,
    'city' => $locality,
    'state' => $state,
    'postalCode' => $postalCode,
    'country' => $country,
    'content' => $content,
    'date' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
    'location' => [
        'lat' => $latitude,
        'lon' => $longitude
    ]
]
]);
```

also you need to add properties (`mapping`) to your document :

PUT request to your elastic search e.g : `localhost:9200/users/_mapping/user`

```
  "properties" : {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
        }
  }
```

and in the query you send like this :

```
{
"filtered" : {
    "query" : {
    },
    "filter" : {
        "geo_distance" : {
            "distance" : "12km",
            "user.location" : {
                "lat" : 40,
                "lon" : -70
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide me where I have to add `"properties" : {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
        }
  }` this?

Comment: in the mapping of your document, you can do it manually by sending post request to `_mapping/user` .. it will  be better if you took a look at the mapping documentation

Comment: I have not idea about mapping but I have this search code:`$query = $client->search([
        'body' => [
            'sort' => [
                'date' => ['order' => 'desc']
            ],
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        'match' => [$filter => $q]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);`

Comment: Do I need to added ` "properties" : {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
        }
  }` code in my above comment code?

Comment: No.. there is something called `mapping`, there is default mapping for each document, you need to send a PUT request using postman to update the `mapping` for user document

Comment: Is it possible to you for provide example as I am new in `elasticsearch`. :)

Comment: I have added `"properties" : {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
        }
  }` in put request but getting error. Can you please check this screen shot: `http://nimb.ws/KRNdBh`

Comment: empty you document first, and make sure lat and lon are double not strings